# ¿Cómo puedo guardar cada iteración de un ciclo for en una variable? C#

Tags: c#, bucle-for, variables

```
using System;

namespace Examen
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {    
            Console.WriteLine("Escribe tu nombre: ");

            string nombre = Console.ReadLine();    
            string[] nombre2 = new string[3];

            for (int i = 0; i<=2; i++)
            {
               Console.WriteLine(nombre[i]);
               //como le hago para que se guarde esto en una variable
            }                                                
        }
    }
}
```

*Me gustaría poder guardar en una variable lo que se imprime en mi consola. *

Comment: ya lo tenes guardado en una variable.. es el array que imprimis....

Answer (score 1):

Si lo quieres guardar en tu arreglo de String `nombre2` puedes hacerlo de esta manera

```
Console.WriteLine("Escribe tu nombre: ");
    string nombre = Console.ReadLine();

    string[] nombre2 = new string[3];
    for (int i = 0; i<3; i++)
    {           
       nombre2[i] = Char.ToString(nombre[i]);
       //Se convierte a String porque el tipo de dato en que viene es char lo cual no es compatible al momento de asignar las letras en tu arreglo nombre2
    }
```

por cada iteración que hace tu ciclo for se guarda en cada posición de tu arreglo `nombre2`

Comment: interaccion o iteracion?, arregla eso en la respuesta q das

Answer (score 1):

Si comprendo bien, lo que quieres hacer, es guardar el nombre, primer y segundo apellido que introduces en *`nombre`*, en *`nombre2[0]`*, *`nombre2[1]`* y *`nombre2[2]`* respectivamente.

```
using System;

namespace Examen
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Escribe tu nombre: ");

            string nombre = Console.ReadLine();
            string[] nombre2 = new string[3];


            for (int i = 0, ind = 0; i <= 2; i++)
            {
                if (nombre.Remove(0,ind).Contains(" "))
                   {
                    nombre2[i] = nombre.Remove(0,ind).Remove(nombre.Remove(0,ind).IndexOf(" "));
                    ind += nombre2[i].Length + 1;
                   }
                else
                    nombre2[i] = nombre.Remove(0,ind);

               Console.WriteLine(nombre2[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: El código de mi respuesta en ejecución]